# Childs Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have lot of `<li></li>` in a page and each `<li>` has a link element `(<a>)`.
I'm trying to add attribute to all `<a>` using select each `<li>` but I can't.

I use the following code to select `<li>` and I can select them but can't add attribute to `links`.

```
<li><a href="#"></a></li>

<script>
$slide.each(function (i) {
    this.id = slideClassPrefix + i;// I can add id to each <li>
    var MyHTML = this.find('a');//This my code for select links :<a>
});
</script>
```

Comment: what attrıbutes do you want to add?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't quite enough code to be certain, but I can give you a pointer.  To set an attribute using jQuery, use `.attr(attributeName, value)`: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
<li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("li").each(function(){
    $(this).find("a").attr("style","color:red;");
  })
</script>
```

As you can read in the docs, you can change the first parameter you pass based on the attribute you want to change, and the second based on the value you want to set.

https://jsfiddle.net/xhk1qbgj/

For your particular case, assuming that `this.find('a')` is fetching the correct jQuery object, you should be able to do something like this:

```
var MyHTML = this.find('a');
MyHTML.attr('style','color:red;');
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually do not have to use `.each` for this. You can use this to directly access all links: `$('li > a').attr("style","color:red;");`

Answer (score 1):

You usually don't have to use `$.each` for simple DOM manipulation with jQuery.

You can set the `id` of each `<li>` and some attribute on each child `<a>` in a single selection:

```js
var i = 0;
var slideClassPrefix = 'li';

$('li')
  .attr('id', function() {
    return slideClassPrefix + i++
  })
  .find('a')
  .attr('href', '#');
```

```css
   li {
 padding: 5px;
   }

#li0 {
  background-color: red;
}
#li1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a>Link one</a>
  </li>
  <li><a>Link two</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```